# Objects and properties

Tags: php, class, object, properties

This is homework. I must say that the instructions are not very clear, but this is what I've "deciphered".
I must create 1 class with 1 "subclass" in different files. Parent class is:

```
<?php
class Objecte
{
var $model;
private $preu;

public function __construct($model,$preu)
{   
    $this->model=$model;
    $this->preu=$preu;  
}
}
?>
```

The "subclass" is:

```
<?php
include('classe_objecte.php');
class Ordinador extends Objecte
{
private $disc_dur;
private $ram;

public function Ordinador($model,$preu,$disc_dur,$ram)
{
    parent::__construct($model,$preu);
    $this->disc_dur=$disc_dur;
    $this->ram=$ram;    
}   
}
?>
```

I must create an "ordinador" object with properties $model,$preu,$disc_dur,$ram to show them later. This information comes from an HTML form that sends it via $_POST to a file called "ordinadors.php". As I'll have more than 1 object, I want the object name to be a variable variable. The name will be the word "ordinador" and a number provided in a session variable called 'numOrdinadorsO'. This is part of the "ordinadors.php" code:

```
include_once('classe_ordinador.php');
/*some other code here*/
$name="ordinador".$_SESSION['numOrdinadorsO'];
$$name=new Ordinador($model,$preu,$disc_dur,$ram);
```

If I var_dump($$name), I get this:

```
object(Ordinador)#1 (4) { ["disc_dur":"Ordinador":private]=> string(3) "100" ["ram":"Ordinador":private]=> string(1) "8" ["model"]=> string(7) "modelo1" ["preu":"Objecte":private]=> string(3) "200" }
```

After creating the object, I must search for an specific "model" and return the other attributes related to that model (preu, ram, etc.). And there problems start. This is the code:

```
function consultarOrdinadorO()
{   
    $model_buscat=$_POST['ordinador_busqueda'];
    $valor=$_SESSION['numOrdinadorsO'];
    $contador=0;
    $trobat=false;
    do 
    {
        for ($i=0; $i<$valor; $i=$i+1)
        {
            $name="ordinador".$i;
            if ($$name->model==$model_buscat)  <-- this is line 91
            {
                echo "Model $model_buscat trobat.";
                $trobat=true;
                break;
            } else {
                $contador+=1;
            }
        }
    }
        while ($trobat==false && $contador<$valor);

    if ($trobat==false)
    {
        echo "Model $model_buscat no trobat.";
    }       
}
```

I get this error (I have insered information of 3 "ordinadors" before):

```
Notice: Undefined variable: ordinador0 in C:\Users\Quenya\IOC\2014-2015\S2\M09 PHP\EAC1\Ejercicios\Exercici2\ordinadors.php on line 91

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\Quenya\IOC\2014-2015\S2\M09 PHP\EAC1\Ejercicios\Exercici2\ordinadors.php on line 91

Notice: Undefined variable: ordinador1 in C:\Users\Quenya\IOC\2014-2015\S2\M09 PHP\EAC1\Ejercicios\Exercici2\ordinadors.php on line 91

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\Quenya\IOC\2014-2015\S2\M09 PHP\EAC1\Ejercicios\Exercici2\ordinadors.php on line 91

Notice: Undefined variable: ordinador2 in C:\Users\Quenya\IOC\2014-2015\S2\M09 PHP\EAC1\Ejercicios\Exercici2\ordinadors.php on line 91

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\Quenya\IOC\2014-2015\S2\M09 PHP\EAC1\Ejercicios\Exercici2\ordinadors.php on line 91
```

Any help?. I've looked in the forums for other questions like this but I haven't found any. I guess I'm probably not understanding well how objects and classes work, but the information provided by the teacher is... very limited.

Thanks a lot!.

UPDATE 1:
Thanks u_mulder, I think I'm seeing some light now. But... I keep having some problems :-(.

Additional information I missed before: I have an HTML form with 2 buttons.
- Button "inserir": I insert the ordinador information. Button "consultar": I insert a model in a text box, and I click the model so it searches the model.

Code in ordinadors.php to specify which funtion call when I click one button or the other:

```
session_start();
include_once('classe_ordinador.php');
$objetos=arrray();
```

//some other code here

```
if (isset($_POST['inserir'])) 
{
    inserirOrdinador();
    inserirOrdinadorS();        
    inserirOrdinadorO();
    var_dump($objetos);
} elseif (isset($_GET['consultar'])=='consultar')
{
    consultarOrdinador();
} elseif (isset($_POST['consultar_ordinador']))
{   
    if (empty($_POST['ordinador_busqueda']))
    {
        echo "Model no introduit.";
    }else
    {

        var_dump($objetos);
        /*
        consultarOrdinadorS();
        consultarOrdinadorO($objetos);
        */
    }
}
```

inserirOrdinadorO now looks like this:

```
function inserirOrdinadorO()
{
      $_SESSION['ordinadorsO']=array('model_ordinadors'=>$_POST['model_ordinadors'],'preu_ordinadors'=>$_POST['preu_ordinadors'],'tamany'=>$_POST['tamany'],'ram'=>$_POST['ram']);

    $model=$_SESSION['ordinadorsO']['model_ordinadors'];
    $preu=$_SESSION['ordinadorsO']['preu_ordinadors'];
    $disc_dur=$_SESSION['ordinadorsO']['tamany'];
    $ram=$_SESSION['ordinadorsO']['ram'];

    global $objetos;
    $obj_id = $_SESSION['numOrdinadorsO'];
    $ord_tmp = new Ordinador($model,$preu,$disc_dur,$ram);
    $objetos[$obj_id] = $ord_tmp;

    $_SESSION['numOrdinadorsO']+=1;
    echo "Objecte Ordinador inserit.</br>";
}
```

So the var_dump($objetos) here is showing me the values I added in inserirOrdinadorO:

```
if (isset($_POST['inserir'])) 
{
    inserirOrdinador();
    inserirOrdinadorS();        
    inserirOrdinadorO();
    var_dump($objetos);
```

but the one here

```
} elseif (isset($_POST['consultar_ordinador']))
{   
    if (empty($_POST['ordinador_busqueda']))
    {
        echo "Model no introduit.";
    }else
    {

        var_dump($objetos);
```

returns this:

```
array(0) { }
```

I guess that it's because it's reading  $objetos here and of course it's empty:

```
session_start();
include_once('classe_ordinador.php');
$objetos=array();
```

But... how do I make it so I can read it from there too?.

Sorry, I'm just begining with php. I read the link you sent but I think I'm missing the point here :-(

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: function `consultarOrdinadorO` doesn't know about `$$name` as the latter is in outer scope. And instead of storing object as `$$name` put them in an array.

Comment: @ u_mulder Sorry, what do you mean when you say " And instead of storing object as $$name put them in an array."?

Comment: Probably not the best way to do it, bus as I needed to keep the info because I navigated to other pages, I stored the array with the objects in a $_SESSION array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when you have a bunch of similar objects and you need to store them - use array.
So, when you have some session value:

```
$obj_id = $_SESSION['numOrdinadorsO'];
// instead of using variable variables use arrays:
$objects = array();  // array to store your objects
$ord_tmp = new Ordinador($model,$preu,$disc_dur,$ram);
// Now you have all your objects of type Ordinador in an array
$objects[$obj_id] = $ord_tmp;
```

Your main problem is function scope. When you call for `consultarOrdinadorO`, this function works in it's own scope, so it doesn't know about any outer variables.
There are two ways of solving this:

In your current function, before you try to access `$$name` you should declare it as `global`, so that function know that this variable is defined somewhere else:

```
for ($i=0; $i<$valor; $i=$i+1)
{
    $name="ordinador".$i;
    // add the following line
    global $$name;
    // other code is the same
```

Or you can pass your variables as arguments. But in your case you don't know how many objects do you have. That's why I advise you to use arrays. After you get all Ordinators to array you can define your function as:

```
function consultarOrdinadorO($ordinators) 
{
    // code skipped
    for ($i=0; $i<$valor; $i=$i+1)
    {
        $cur_obj = $ordinators[$i];
        if ($cur_obj->model ==  )
    // code skipped
}
```

Assuming you collect all your objects earlier to `$objects` array, function call will be `consultarOrdinadorO($objects)`

More about functions here: https://www.php.net/language.functions.php

Comment: Thanks u_mulder, I've included an update as I think I'm starting to see the light but I have some additional problems now (related with scope, I fear).